# Move and rename files within a tar archive

Tags: linux, unix, tar

I have a tar archive called MyFiles.tar that contains a folder named Directory. Within the folder I have forty or more files named:

```
MyFile_01.txt.gz 
MyFile_02.txt.gz 
MyFile_03.txt.gz 
MyFile_04.txt.gz 
MyFile_05.txt.gz...
```

for instance:

```
tar -tf MyFiles.tar
```

yields:

```
Directory/MyFile_01.txt.gz
Directory/MyFile_02.txt.gz
Directory/MyFile_03.txt.gz
Directory/MyFile_04.txt.gz
Directory/MyFile_05.txt.gz...
```

I would like to delete the "Directory" folder and rename the files so that

```
tar -tf MyFiles.tar
```

yields:

```
Sample_01.txt.gz
Sample_02.txt.gz
Sample_03.txt.gz
Sample_04.txt.gz
Sample_05.txt.gz...
```

Comment: Extract, cd into the Directory, then archive

Comment: @user3791372 is there a way to do this in one line?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, "one line":

```
tar xf MyFiles.tar; cd Directory; for n in MyFile_[0-9]*.txt.gz ;do [ -f "$n" ] && mv -f "$n" $(echo $n|sed -e s/MyFile/Sample/); done; tar cf ../Sample.tar Sample_[0-9]*.txt.gz; cd ..; rm -rf Directory
```